# Excel VBA Index Match Only Blank Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of data, eg. 5000 row, some already filled up with data, some is blank, i want to add a formula to the blank cells, i have below vba codes but having problem in the formula with fixed row number, ie. E3435, how can i replace it with vba code if i need to add formula based on different row number? Thanks

```
Sub FillInBlanks()
Dim rng As RANGE, cell As RANGE
Set rng = ActiveSheet.RANGE("c3:A4133")
For Each cell In rng
   If IsEmpty(cell) Then
   cell.formula = "=DATE(YEAR(E3435),MONTH(E3435),DAY(E3435))"
   End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an xlR1C1 style formula as described in the linked duplicate. Use .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) to write all of the formulas at once.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightenment, let me try later

Comment: Hi Jeeped, your code working perfectly! awesome!! I have small problem, how to make the code stop at last row? as the code run till row 1048576.

Comment: It shouldn't but you could add error control with this small edit `set blnks = intersect(.parent.usedrange, .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks))`.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped!